# How can I check if the first index in this string is = '1' and then remove it?

Tags: javascript, formatter

I am creating a phone number formatter and all is working except this part. The error I am running into is this: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined". I tried using .includes('1',0) instead, but that did not work either.

```
// If cleanNumber has a country code(1), remove it
  if((cleanNumber.indexOf("1")) = 0){
    cleanNumber = cleanNumber.substring(1); //removes first character = "1"
    activeSheet.getRange(i,3).setValue(cleanNumber);  
    Logger.log("Country code removed: " + cleanNumber);
    }
```

Comment: use `startWith` when u want to check a string. Also your variable `cleanNumber` is `undefined` and not a string.

Comment: @Sysix It's also available for strings!

Comment: When you see such error message, then trying with another method like `includes` is the wrong reaction. Read and understand the error message first, then debug and check why `cleanNumber` is not defined.

Comment: @JoakimL.Christiansen thanks updated

Comment: Where did you get cleanNumber from?

Comment: Using the startWith it's the best option, you can also use the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to avoid the "cannot read property of undefined" error, just like this:

`if(cleanNumber?.startsWith("1"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=` is an assignment operator.

`==` is a comparison operator.

Use `==` instead.

```js
if ((cleanNumber.indexOf("1")) == 0) {
    cleanNumber = cleanNumber.substring(1); //removes first character = "1"
    activeSheet.getRange(i, 3).setValue(cleanNumber);
    Logger.log("Country code removed: " + cleanNumber);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked!! I appreciate the help.